# Animate infinite scrolling of an image in a seamless loop not working when back from back ground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have the following code that run an endless loop of the same image

the problem is when the user minimize the application, and get back to it, the image stop animating and it totally disappear

Here is my code:

```
-(void)cloudScroll
{
UIImage *cloudsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TitleClouds.png"];
UIColor *cloudPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:cloudsImage];
CALayer *cloud = [CALayer layer];
cloud.backgroundColor = cloudPattern.CGColor;
cloud.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1);
cloud.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
CGSize viewSize = self.cloudsImageView.bounds.size;
cloud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cloudsImage.size.width + viewSize.width, viewSize.height);
[self.cloudsImageView.layer addSublayer:cloud];

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointZero;
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(-cloudsImage.size.width, 0);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint];
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
animation.duration = 3.0;
[cloud addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol Reference. In the discussion part of method called `applicationDidEnterBackground:` you can find answer on your question.

you can try re-firing your animation upon re-opening of the application

Comment: Does anyone have a sample project zip in which this runs and works?  My test didn't have errors, but I never saw any images scrolling in my view.  Thank you.