# CABasicAnimation - Infinite scrolling of an image on retina device is garbled

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cabasicanimation

In a similar post, I found a solution to animating a scrolling image infinitely:

[Animate infinite scrolling of an image in a seamless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790079/animate-infinite-scrolling-of-an-image-in-a-seamless-loop)

While this solution works beautifully, there seems to be an issue when running on a retina device.  In particular, I am running this project on an iPad only.  A non-retina iPad 2 scrolls the image without any problems.  But run on a retina iPad 3 or 4 the image is a mess!  It's difficult to describe, but the best I can say is that it is garbled. Pixels are stretched every which way.  It resembles a Jackson Pollak painting.

Screen shot:

[http://imgur.com/Q7n08kv](https://imgur.com/Q7n08kv)

I tested this using a non-retina image (non 2x) and a retina version (@2x).  The image is large - full screen (landscape) and is 4 panels wide (4096 x 768).  I played around with smaller images but with the same result.

**Is there a limitation with the scrolling functionality of CABasicAnimation that would affect retina devices?**  Here is the code I am using (as contributed by rob mayoff):

```
UIImage *crawlImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CrawlBackground.png"];
UIColor *crawlPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:crawlImage];
self.crawlLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.crawlLayer.backgroundColor = crawlPattern.CGColor;

self.crawlLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1);
self.crawlLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);

self.crawlLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, crawlImage.size.width + 1024, crawlImage.size.height);

[self.backgroundCrawl.layer addSublayer:self.crawlLayer];
self.backgroundCrawl.layer.zPosition = 0;

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointZero;
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(-crawlImage.size.width, 0);

self.crawlLayerAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
self.crawlLayerAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
self.crawlLayerAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint];
self.crawlLayerAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint];
self.crawlLayerAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
self.crawlLayerAnimation.duration = 30;   // nn seconds to complete the cycle
```

Comment: Perhaps you could upload a screen shot to imgur.com and post a link to it.

Comment: I've edited the question and added a link to a screen capture of what the problem looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`self.crawlLayer.contents = (id)crawlImage.CGImage;`

or:

```
self.crawlLayer.contents = (__bridge id)([crawlImage CGImage]);
```

This should fix it. Allowing large images to scroll correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.crawlLayer = [CALayer layer];
```

As soon as you make a layer you should set its `contentsScale`:

```
self.crawlLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Otherwise it may not display correctly on double-resolution screens.