# How to make this "tape rolling" effect - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a game and I'm trying to do an effect where the scenery on the sides is changing a lot, I'm not using sprite kit or anything, just UIKit because its a simple game. Essentially I have a png that is double the screen size of an iPhone 5 (568px x 2 = 1136px), that starts in the middle of the screen when the game starts, and it scrolls down as the player navigates through the game. I want it to reset and roll through the game after it's center has passed a certain point, so I thought to write this:

```
    if (scenery.center.y > 1136) {
    scenery.center = CGPointMake(scenery.center.x, -568);
}
```

I chose `scenery.center.y > 1136` because its the bottom of the screen x2. Then it makes a point at -568, so there is 1 full screen where there is no scenery. Is there a better way to go about doing this, and making it continuous?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790079/animate-infinite-scrolling-of-an-image-in-a-seamless-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used CABasic Animations to accomplish this:

```
+(void)animateView:(UIView *)view {

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];

    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.fromValue = view.frame.origin.x - view.frame.size.width;
    animation.toValue = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    animation.duration = 0.5;
    animation.autoreverses = NO;
    animation.beginTime = 0; // ignore delay time for now
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"horizontal_animation"];
```

}

The view represents the UIImageView that I'm moving across the screen. I start it off the screen (see fromValue) and move it to the opposite side just off the screen (see toValue). If you need vertical animations as well, you can create another [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"] with similar values shown above.

Also, if you want something besides a linear animation, just replace kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear. In its place just start typing kCAMediaTiming ... and let the wonders of autocomplete take you the rest of the way.

Comment: Where do you add this section of the code? @eckyzero, what do I declare in the .h and do I make a method for this

Comment: You can add it anywhere. I put mine in a separate AnimationManager.m file with the rest of my animations. Then I put +(void)animateView:(UIView *)view; in the AnimationManager.h file. Then, from my ViewController I call [AnimationManager animateView:self.backgroundImageView];

Comment: Glad to see it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

What I always do for things like this is to use two images. When one gets just off the screen on the bottom, move it right back up to just off the screen on the top. In your case you could just cut your scenery image in half.