# Cloud moving animation in Swift? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, swift5

We are following this tutorial to http://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/core-animation-scroll-layer-cascrolllayer

As per their tutorial animation will stop based on the layer bounds reached. How to do the cloud moving animation by using core animation or in Imageview?

Is it possible?

Gif or Lottie animation not needed here, we excepting through code.

Note that we have tried their code and its working but lack is there as i mentioned above.

How to keep on moving animation like cloud does?

Think twice before devoting this question.

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var translation: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    public var currentWidth : CGFloat = {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        return width
    }()

    public var currentHeight : CGFloat = {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        return width
    }()

    
    lazy var scrollLayer : CAScrollLayer = {
        let scrollLayer = CAScrollLayer() // 8
        scrollLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: currentWidth, height: currentHeight) // 9
        scrollLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.size.height/2) // 10
        scrollLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor // 11
//        scrollLayer.borderWidth = 5.0 // 12
        scrollLayer.scrollMode = CAScrollLayerScrollMode.horizontally // 13
        return scrollLayer
    }()
    
    lazy var displayLink: CADisplayLink = {
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(scrollLayerScroll))
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRange(minimum: 5.0, maximum: 8.0, __preferred: 6.0)
        } else {
            displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 5
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        return displayLink
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let img = UIImage(named: "new") { // 1
                let imageSize = img.size
                let layer = CALayer() // 2
                layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: currentWidth * 50, height: currentHeight * 5) // 3
//                layer.position = CGPoint(x: imageSize.width/2, y: imageSize.height/2) // 4
                layer.contents = img.cgImage // 5
                view.layer.addSublayer(scrollLayer) // 6
                scrollLayer.addSublayer(layer) // 7
            }
        displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: .common)

    }
    @objc func scrollLayerScroll() {
        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: translation, y: 0.0)
        scrollLayer.scroll(newPoint)
        translation += 10.0
//        if translation > 1600.0 {
////            stopDisplayLink()
//        }
    }
    func stopDisplayLink() {
        displayLink.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Here setting width too high for animating the layer extra time

```
layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: currentWidth * 50, height: currentHeight * 5) // 3
```

Comment: You should make your question self-contained. Edit your question to show exactly what code you tried when you say "we have tried their code".

Comment: If you don't want the animation to "stop" when the end of the layer is reached, what do you want it to do then? Wrap around from the start? That would require the image of the clouds to have specific characteristics. I assume you have that already?

Comment: @Sweeper Check my edited code..

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with following solution by rob mayoff

[Animate infinite scrolling of an image in a seamless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790079/animate-infinite-scrolling-of-an-image-in-a-seamless-loop)

Please find the updated code.

```
class CloudPassingVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageToAnimate: UIImageView!
    
    
    var cloudLayer: CALayer? = nil
    var cloudLayerAnimation: CABasicAnimation? = nil
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cloudScroll()
    }
    func cloudScroll() {
        let cloudsImage = UIImage(named: "clouds")
        let cloudPattern = UIColor(patternImage: cloudsImage!)
        cloudLayer = CALayer()
        cloudLayer!.backgroundColor = cloudPattern.cgColor

        cloudLayer!.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1)

        cloudLayer!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)

        let viewSize = imageToAnimate.bounds.size
        cloudLayer!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (cloudsImage?.size.width ?? 0.0) + viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height)

        imageToAnimate.layer.addSublayer(cloudLayer!)

        let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: -(cloudsImage?.size.width ?? 0.0), y: 0)
        cloudLayerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        cloudLayerAnimation!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        cloudLayerAnimation!.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: startPoint)
        cloudLayerAnimation!.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: endPoint)
        cloudLayerAnimation!.repeatCount = 600
        cloudLayerAnimation!.duration = 10.0
        applyCloudLayerAnimation()
    }
    func applyCloudLayerAnimation() {
        cloudLayer!.add(cloudLayerAnimation!, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```